# How to steal build an app of two html files with shared dependencies in JavascriptMVC

Tags: javascriptmvc

I have an application with two html files:

- app/page1.html
- app/page2.html

These pages share dependencies, i.e -jquery / plugins and I want to use the "steal build" script to build them efficiently.

I found some [examples](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!steal.build) and [questions](https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/multi-build-and-shared-packages) that describe this issue and give examples on multiple apps, but didn't give a solution for this problem.

But when I try to build with this line for example I'm getting errors:

```
js steal/buildjs app/page1.html app/page2.html -to app
```

Anyone had experience with this scenario?

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good soul (asavoy) created a pull request that deals with this issue, apparently it was a bug in the new version:

https://github.com/jupiterjs/steal/pull/83

I'll post an update once I'll test it out myself.